# Problems Deploying application to Weblogic through the Admin Console

Tags: eclipse, deployment, struts2, weblogic-10.x, action-mapping

I'm using Weblogic 10.3.5.  When I deploy my Struts2 application locally in eclipse, it runs fine.  When I try to deploy my application through the Admin console, I get a Struts 2 error, name not found for action.

When I look at the .war file, it has all the libraries and classes.  I followed these [directions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/apirefs.1111/e13952/taskhelp/deployment/InstallApplicationsAndModules.html) for deploying through the Admin Console.  I can successfully deploy through the Admin Console, but when I try and use the test links for the application, I get the same error.  If I try to access the application through the url:

```
http://localhost:7001/app-name
```

I get the same error.

Here is the stack trace:

> [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '8' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default
>   (self-tuning)'] WARN org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher - Could
>   not find action or result: /eServices/login.action There is no Action
>   mapped for namespace [/] and action name [login] associated with
>   context path [/eServices]. - [unknown location] at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:185)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.prepare(StrutsActionProxy.java:63)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(StrutsActionProxyFactory.java:37)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(DefaultActionProxyFactory.java:58)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:552)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
>     at
>   oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:111)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:313)
>     at
>   oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:413)
>     at
>   oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:94)
>     at
>   oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:161)
>     at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:71)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
>     at
>   oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:136)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3715)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3681)
>     at
>   weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
>     at
>   weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2183)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)
>     at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)  at
>   weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)

What am I doing wrong?  Why can I access the application when I deploy it through eclipse, but I can't access the application when I deploy it through the Admin Console.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is the error message/stack trace? Sounds like a classpath issue still but need the full trace to provide help

Comment: @better_use_mkstemp, I've updated the post with the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your struts.xml file in WEB-INF/classes is somehow wrong when you're trying a manual deploy. Crack open your .ear/.war file and see what's in your struts.xml (if it even exists). Eclipse might be automatically putting it into a folder for you that doesn't get deployed when you do it manually. Below is a working example for reference:

```
<struts>
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
<package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">

    <action name="myAction" 
        class="com.something.myAction" >
        <result name="success">pages/myPage.jsp</result>
    </action>

</package>
</struts>
```

If the project root context is “app-name“, you can access the above action via a URL like –
`http://domain:8080/app-name/myAction.action`

Comment: The struts.xml file does exist.  It has a few things in it to alter the Struts2 constants.  We are using annotations.